# UIApplication sharedApplication keeps executing when going back to the app and relaunching

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate

The following code works fine but when I go back to my app it keeps on executing the following code but I don't know why and how to stop it.
I think it is only happening in ios5.0 :
app flow - rootviewcontroller -> mainviewcontroller ->webview

the following code is called in **shouldstartloadrequest** method of a webview in mainviewcontroller

```
@property (readwrite, retain) UIWebView *_loginWebView;
...
..
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_loginWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

//following gets called whenever webview gets a request to open url

```
   - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
            //return no is a special case there is more code in the method which I am not showing here
           if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:myURL]) 
           {
                  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
           }
           else
           {
                  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newPath]];
           }
           return NO;
     }
     //above is a special case

}
```

head tag content -

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <!-- iOS Stuff -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/...."/>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <script async="async" src="https://......."></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
..........
  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Where is this code being called? What method?

Comment: shouldstartloadrequest method

Comment: Well, by reading the two available answers I couldn't understand your problem. You don't want the webview to refresh everytime your app goes to foreground right? What I would say is that you get some control flags that you can check on webview:shouldStartLoadRequest: and decide if you want it to load or not. The fact is that we don't know why it's called and maybe this is its behavior. If that's so you just have to go around it. If this seems completely off then maybe I didn't understand a thing.

Comment: may be i put it in a wrong way - try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491584/ios-app-hits-straight-shouldstartloadwithrequest-after-coming-from-background-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug with IOS 5.0 where if you went back to a webview on app's return to foreground, it refreshes it....just the way safari does it...

but apple fixed this bug in IOS 6.0

So nothing could've been done about it.

Answer (score 0):

does myURL have a meta refresh set in the header? If the web page is reloading, this method will get called. It will also get called if there are redirects.

Comment: no but what does it matter? because it only happen once in 3 times. look at the flow -> myapp is running - open 2nd app - now app runs in background - press home key - open my myapp again - it goes straight to second app

Comment: You need to show more code. Show the entire method and also what is calling that method (is it in viewDidAppear? applicationDidBecomeActive?)

Comment: that is a standard webview delegate

Comment: Can you show the <HEAD> tag of the html for the site you're loading?

Comment: Also, why the heck are you called your AppDelegate inside viewDidLoad and even worse, why are you setting the variable to nil?

Comment: i normally dont do that, its just me in an exploded state where I dont know what to do

Comment: Got it. Could you post what's inside the <HEAD> tag of the URL you are loading?

Comment: i just did but its not much there

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, the problem is

1. start your app, go to the mainViewController, after the view did load, it will let iOS to open a url in another application.
2. the other application is opened, and when you back to your application, the web view reload the url automatically.

so, problem is why the webview reload the url automaticlly.

from the code above, it likes there is no need to use web view, because the delegate always return No, and do something others.

I don't know why this happens now, if you can , just remove the web view troubled this.

and this answer will be deleted.

Comment: thanks wubao this is what i thought too but the 2nd time around viewidload doesn't even get called, it is hitting shouldstartloadwithrequest straight when i go back to the app

Comment: I have already tried C with no luck, I have got a temporary solution using nsnotification - UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification but still loking for a better solution

Comment: return no is a special case there is more code in the mehtod which I am not showing here

Comment: hey could you repost your A,B,C